# Oracle service bus Invocation Error

Tags: oracle, soa, osb

Whenever I try to invoke a proxy service in OSB it gives me error. Here's the error I see:

```
com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: 
The invocation resulted in an error:
Unknown error while processing message for service ProxyService {Proxy service path}
```

A HTTP 500 is returned.

In the message flow I can see a request was returned as it is saying "No service has been invoked." In the logs I can see "Error to place router information".

Any ideas for how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 is essentially "Internal Server Error". Check OSB server logs for full stack trace. The problem is around the area where Proxy Service has been deployed.